# Sagpay form integration not working on Test enviroment

Tags: opayo

we have setup sagepay form integration.

```
 <form action="https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="VPSProtocol" value="3.0"/>
 <input type="text" name="TxType" value="PAYMENT"/>
 <input type="text" name="Vendor" value="<?php echo $vendor; ?>"/>
 <input type="text" name="Crypt" value="<?php echo $crypt; ?>"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Pay"/>
 </form>
```

crypt working with https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp enviroment but when i testing same crypt with test envrionment https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp it's always give me 5080 error.

also i checked my test sagepay account in that no transaction found to check 5080 error.i checked encryption password also all things are correct.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your question has been answered here:

[Sagepay form Integration keeps giving error 5080 (Form transaction registration failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480452/sagepay-form-integration-keeps-giving-error-5080-form-transaction-registration)

@S.Simkhada posted: "I have finally figured it out. I was sending the crypt field across but not the other data like txt type."

See that post.

Comment: but same crypt perfectly run on live environment.

Comment: I would contact SagePay support.

Comment: got help from Sagepay support team.
 have to sight the new encryption password,